# JQuery UI Click call works on local machine but not when published to server - also using CakePHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, mod-rewrite, cakephp, jquery-events

I have some javascript that looks like this:

```
$('.resultitem').click(function(event){
     alert('check this gets called');                      
     location.href='viewinfo/'+$(this).attr('rel');
});
```

this code works fine on my local machine but after uploading to the server it doesn't seem to get called at all. Can anybody help me understand why?

UPDATE: As mentioned below this was caused by a script error higher up. While debugging with firebug, I noticed on the server that in the net tab a GET jquery.cookie.js failes with a code of 406 not acceptable.

I had to rename to jquerycookie.js to keep this particular hosting provider happy. I did a little more research and this could be due to the following:

"anything with .cookie. in it triggers an Apache mod_security warning, stopping the file from being served, effectively making this unable to work"

Comment: Is this running in a `document.ready` handler?

Comment: yes, it is running in a document.ready handler

Comment: there's a chance that some other javascript is erroring above it and it's never being reached. Have you tried debugging the javascript with FireBug or Chrome Inspector or IE Developer Tools or....

Comment: ok, weird I am getting an error "$.cookie is not a function".

Comment: Might have nothing to do with it but should you not have a 'return false' at the end of the click handler to prevent event bubble up?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including your JavaScript files using Cake's HTML helper? For example:

`echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery-1.4.3.min'));`

Note that following Cake's conventions, I've left off the `.js` file extension. In my experience, this has created problems where the production server thinks that `.min` is the file extension and attempts to load a nonexistent file called `jquery-1.4.3.min`, which means jQuery isn't loaded and therefore the snippet you've posted would fail.

I'm not sure if this is how you're loading your scripts, but in general it's safer to use the entire file name, like so:

`echo $this->Html->script(array('jquery-1.4.3.min.js'));`